# How can I find the source code that relates to keyboard settings UIs

Tags: settings, keyboard, development

I'm really keen to tackle some minor bug-fixes (I hope) for Elementary OS but am struggling to find the relevant source code amongst the plethora of source code branches.

Major barriers to me finding the relavant source are

1. being new to BZR
2. being new to Launchpad
3. being new to dealing with Linux distribution projects and how they are built and structured

The bugs I would like to look into both relate to the keyboard settings dialog/application:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1487760 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1486857

Can anyone offer any pointers for where to look for the source? Plus any online resources for grokking how these projects hang together and are built?

Footnote: I have already found the source repo(s)? for the OS on launchpad and have managed to checkout the trunk and build the ISO. Looking at the source of that branch showed very little code however, and I am struggling to see where it is pulling in all its pieces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, there is a separate project in Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-keyboard.

Also of interest to anyone else starting out like I am is this google doc on building large-scale Ubuntu derivatives. The doc is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RPPF14h1Sw2gQjGTuZjUIlNHnGrafS8ekhFjJM9MT00/edit

In terms of how the various components of the distro hang together - they each are packaged and built individually, the main build distro simply has a pointer to each package. So you could remove the package from the distro by removing a line of code. A user could then install the package separately themselves (please someone correct me if I have this wrong).

Comment: [This metaproject](https://launchpad.net/elementary) will probably be helpful. It lists all the other projects associated with elementary.